second power in exponential
I am struggling with raising some powered expression to another power, like $(a^b)^c$ which should equal to $a^{bc}$. As two examples
$(3^2)^3=9^3=729=3^6$
$3=3^{2/2}=(3^2)^{1/2}=(3^{1/2})^2$.
Now if we use complex exponential as the base of powers then this rule is true for
$e^{i\pi}=e^{i\pi * 3/3}=(e^{i3\pi})^{1/3}=(e^{i\pi/3})^3=-1$
but it is not true for the following expressions
$\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=e^{i\pi/3}=e^{i2\pi/6}=(e^{i2\pi})^{1/6}=1^{1/6}=\sqrt[6]{1}=1$
$\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=e^{i\pi/3}=e^{i2\pi/6}=(e^{i\pi/6})^2=(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{i}{2})^2=\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
I am not sure in what part I am going wrong way.

complex roots can in general have more than one solution, for example $(-1)^6 = 1^3 = 1$ is also a solution of $x^6 - 1 = 0$. This means your calculation depends on your choice of the sixth root of $1$. You can check by calculating $\left(\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^6.$

The rule you're referring to doesn't hold in general for complex numbers. You will find lots of similar questions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fake-proofs?tab=Frequent.

You're forgetting that $\sqrt[6] 1$ is not  only $1$

Thank you all for your comments, Now I see clearly where I went wrong.

This one is tricky because your misunderstanding is with notation, not with mathematics. You don't even need to get into complex numbers to run into this problem.
$$-1=(-1)^{\frac{2}{2}}=\left((-1)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{1}=1$$
The issue is that $f(x)=x^2$ is not a one-to-one function, which means that it can't have a proper inverse. The problem in the example above is that $\sqrt{x}$ does not return both roots of $x$, because a function can't have multiple outputs for the same input. Instead, someone defined it to return a single result, specifically the positive real one if it exists. This is called the principal value of the radical. $\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is indeed a 6th root of $1$ and is a solution to $x^6=1$. It just isn't the root we chose to be the principal value of $\sqrt[6]{1}$.
